# C: d_name of readdir cannot be converted into String

Tags: c, directory, operating-system, filesystems, system-calls

My code is as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  DIR *myDir;
  struct dirent *myFile;

  myDir = opendir("/");
  while ((myFile = readdir(myDir)))
  {
    char myStr[256] = "foo";
    printf("%s\n", myFile->d_name);
    printf("%s\n", myStr);
  }
  closedir(myDir);
  return (0);
}
```

The above code works. But then I tried to replace `char myStr[256] = "foo";` by `char myStr[256] = myFile->d_name;`, and I got the error message "error: invalid initializer" when I try to compile.

Any idea how to fix? It seems that I need to choose another type for `char myStr[256]`, but I'm not sure which type should I choose...

Answer (score 3):

The initializer for an array has to be a literal, it won't copy from a variable.

To copy a string, use `strcpy()`

```
char myStr[256];
strcpy(myStr, myFile->d_name);
printf("%s\n", myStr);
```

Comment: Note that I can hack your program by making a file name longer than 255 characters.

Comment: I don't think you can have a filename longer than 255 characters.

Comment: Google agrees. You are lucky though. Maybe next year they'll upgrade it to 511!